# create separate dataframes from single time series dataframe based on value in one column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a time series dataframe (date is index) with 10 columns of values. One column is an 'indicator' column that is 0 or 1. When the indicator = 1 for a given set of dates/rows I'd like to create a separate dataframe for that group of rows and save it as a csv. Then for the next group of rows where 'indicator' = 1 in the original dataframe I'd like to create another dataframe and save it to a new csv file. My data looks like this:

| date index | col1 | col2 | . . . | indicator | col10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-02 | 12 | 9 |  | 0 | 23 |
| 2022-03-03 | 112 | 91 |  | 0 | 20 |
| 2022-03-04 | 2 | 3 |  | 1 | 23 |
| 2022-03-05 | 132 | 23 |  | 1 | 29 |
| 2022-03-06 | 142 | 1 |  | 1 | 33 |
| 2022-03-07 | 22 | 0 |  | 0 | 2 |
| 2022-03-08 | 34 | 77 |  | 0 | 4 |
| 2022-03-09 | 6 | 45 |  | 0 | 34 |
| 2022-03-10 | 45 | 23 |  | 1 | 3 |
| 2022-03-11 | 87 | 2 |  | 1 | 56 |
| 2022-03-12 | 2 | 1 |  | 0 | 31 |

I'd like to generate new dataframes from the original dataframe for each group of rows (days) where "indicator" = 1.

From the example table above, the process would result in two new dataframes: one for rows 2022-03-04 through 2022-03-06 and one for rows 2022-03-10 through 2022-03-11, each saved as separate csv files (eg indicator1-1.csv, indicator1-2.csv, etc)

I've been trying variations on df.groupby['indicator'] without success.

Suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
# which rows are to keep?
m = df['indicator'].eq(1)

# group by successive 1s
dfs = [g for _,g in df[m].groupby((~m).cumsum())]

print(dfs)
```